# Java HEAD/GET request versus Linux request

Tags: java, linux, http, web

Hopefully it's a simple question. I am trying to make a HEAD/GET request to a university server, making sure the server even exists. The HEAD request sends first, and if that fails we send a GET request. Unfortunately, both requests are returning 403's. This is using a little Java program I made.

Now when I use Linux to send HEAD/GET requests, I get a 200 response with both. So what is the deal here? Is there a difference in information requested with Java compared to Linux? Thank you in advance for anything!

EDIT: Here is the code. The command I use to run it is simply "java FILE URL". The Linux command I compared it to is "curl -I URL".

```
public static boolean urlHeadRequest(String link)
{
    PageConnection conn;
    boolean problem = false;
    int status;
    URL url;
    try{
        if(link.indexOf("#") != -1){
            link = link.substring(0, link.lastIndexOf("#"));
        }

        url = new URL(link);
        conn = new PageConnection(url);
        System.out.println("Requesting: " + link);
        //Set the request method to HEAD - only get back header information
        conn.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
        status = conn.getHttpResponseCode();
        System.out.println("\tHEAD request status: " + status);
        //Try GET request if HEAD fails, this takes longer but is more likely to succeed
        if ((status >= 200) && (status < 299)){
            System.out.println("Server is good.");
              }
        else { //Server is down
            conn = new PageConnection(url);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            status = conn.getHttpResponseCode();
            System.out.println("HEAD request failed. Using GET request...");
            if ((status < 200) || (status >= 299)){
                problem = true;
                System.out.println(link + " is unreachable with status " + status);
            }
            else{
                problem = false;
                System.out.println("URL is reachable using GET request with status " + status);
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error: Server is not responding or does not exist.");
    }



    return problem;

}
```

PageConnection is a custom class. I think these two functions might be relevant:

```
public void setRequestMethod(String method) throws ProtocolException
    {
            huc.setRequestMethod(method);
    }

    /**
     * @return HTTP status code, an integer between 0 and 999.  For details see <a href="http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRESP.html">W3C HTTP Response Codes</a>
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public int getHttpResponseCode() throws IOException
    {
            this.huc.getErrorStream();
            return this.huc.getResponseCode();
    }
```

Hopefully this helps a bit.

Comment: I set the user-agent like was suggested below, but it appears to have not worked. `huc.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)");` I will try diff'ing the headers, but it will take some time. Thanks for the suggestions, all.

Answer (score 0):

Not really a straight forward question to be answered. But with the given input, I'll try to come up with suggestions.

1. Setup a network sniffer to read what are the HTTP headers that are passed on in both the cases. Something like wireshark would be of help.
2. If you find any difference in the headers, you can try to match Java code with Linux script headers. I'm assuming the URLs in both cases are in exact match.
3. It is even possible that servers intelligently block the requests if they find something fishy - say programmed numerous requests which might result in DOS attack etc.
4. Another possibility is that the university url is shielded with a load balancer which is redirecting your both requests to different servers which are behaving differently - Linux / Java wouldn't matter in this case, just a luck by chance.

If possible, share the url, java code and linux script / command that's being used so that the community can help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting the User-Agent? Sometimes security policies will block unexpected Agents to cut down on automated crawlers (since all legitimate browser traffic will provide a variable there).

I'd follow the previous users comment and diff the headers, and attempt to make them match. 403's are usually indicative of a server refusing to field your request because it didn't like something in the header.